# Android: Run code when application is permanently closed

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

So I have code that I want called when my application is closed. Not just when it is sent to the background or the surface is destroyed. How do I do this? Is there a method that I can override in a `SurfaceView` or `Activity` class?

**New Edit** - current `BackgroundService` class:

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {
    private String savedString;

    public void onCreate() {
        System.out.println("Service created");
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        System.out.println("start command: ");
        savedString = intent.getStringExtra("myString);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        System.out.println("the saved string was: " + savedString);
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
         System.out.println("destroyed service");
         super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Where I then have this in my other class:

```
 Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), BackgroundService.class);
 serviceIntent.putExtra("myString", "this is my saved string");
 activity.startService(serviceIntent);
```

Comment: you need to create a service to handle this. its nothing to do with your view/activity. it can handle when the application is swiped away from the recent apps panel

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "when my application is closed"? Do you mean "when my process is terminated"? Do you mean something else?

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes when the process is terminated. For example when you open the running apps screen, and swipe away the app to stop it from running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add a background service

```
public class BackgroundServices  extends Service
{


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "start", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onCreate();
}



@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {



}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

then in your activity. where you want to trigger this service

use

```
 startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), BackgroundServices.class));
```

in your case it will be call on onDestory function of that activity

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working. I will post the code that I currently have now.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes when the process is terminated

That is not possible in general. Nothing in your app is called when the process is terminated.

> For example when you open the running apps screen, and swipe away the app to stop it from running

That is a task removal. It *may* result in your process being terminated, and there are many ways in which your process can be terminated that has nothing to do with task removal.

To detect task removal, override `onTaskRemoved()` in a `Service`.

Comment: Can you look at my updated post and the code I added? I created a class that extends a `Service` and started it by calling `activity.startService()` but nothing in the class seems to be called.

Comment: @Ryan: Well, there doesn't seem to very much correct with that implementation or how you are using it. I suggest that you write a regular service (i.e., get rid of the `StorableMethod` crap) and use it properly (i.e., do not create an instance of it yourself). Be sure to register the service in the manifest. Creating and using services is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html), [the JavaDocs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), plus books and courses on Android app development.

Comment: Using the `StorableMethods` why my way of adding flexibility. And also because there were variables that needed to be accessed from other classes that wouldn't be defined until later. Adding `StorableMethods` allowed me to create the `Service` at certain points and customize the methods with the variables needed without having to declare them all `public static`. And everything worked once I added the `Service` to the manifest, which I had forgotten to do.

Comment: Nevermind, it appears that when I set the methods, the code in the methods is never called thus making my idea useless. So my question then is how do I actually use variables from other classes without setting them all `public static`. Because it seems that doing it the proper way doesn't allow me to create a constructor so I can't pass variables in that way.

Comment: Ok, after doing some research I think I figured out how I am supposed to do this, including sending information. I'm going to add the code now, would you mind checking?

Comment: @Ryan: What you have now seems fine. If you need richer communication with other components (particularly for information arising from the service), consider an event bus (greenrobot's EventBus, `LocalBroadcastManager`, something RxJava-based, `MutableLiveData`, etc.).